# Force retesting or disable test caching

Tags: testing, go

**Problem:**

When I run the same go test twice the second run is not done at all. The results are the cached ones from the first run.

```
PASS    
ok      tester/apitests    (cached)
```

**Links**

I already checked https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags but there is no cli flag for that purpose.

**Question:**

**Is there a possibility to force go test to always run test and not to cache test results.**

Comment: There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things. -- Phil Karlton

Answer (score 399, accepted):

There are a few options as described in the [testing flags docs](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags):

- `go clean -testcache`: expires all test results
- use non-cacheable flags on your test run. The idiomatic way is to use `-count=1`

That said, changes in your code or test code will invalidate the cached test results (there's extended logic when using local files or environment variables as well), so you should not need to invalidate the test cache manually.

Comment: It's still useful in case you're testing against a moving dependency e.g. a database where you setup / teardown the dependency but not your code. Looks like OP was testing against a non stubbed API which is what prompted their question.

Comment: is it possible to clean the cache for specific tests only?

Comment: Note that `go clean -testcache ./...` works too (at the top of a monorepo)

Comment: I've opened an issue to make this better as well:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/39056?ts=4

Comment: great answer, I was needing this because i ran ttwice the test suite with a different set of env vars. This is required to trigger the test of different implementation that must pass the same series of tests. This helped to prevent code duplication.

Comment: It can be useful when tests are flaky and results can vary from run to run: relying on tests being invalidated by code changes assumes reproducible tests, which is is only guaranteed for unit tests: for integration tests, where the source of cache invalidations my rest outside the code, it's better to use -count=1.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is useful when running benchmarks as well with 'go test -bench=...' - I have in fact a suite which was misbehaving (some tests where lagging behind for no real reason) right up until I actual run 'go clean -testcache'. Weird but there you have it.

Comment: The second point "use non-cacheable flags on your test run" is actually quite good. The [Golang docs for test package](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/test#:~:text=The%20idiomatic%20way%20to%20disable%0Atest%20caching%20explicitly%20is%20to%20use%20%2Dcount%3D1.) states "The idiomatic way to disable test caching explicitly is to use `-count=1`". This is because setting `-count` to anything above zero has the side effect of disabling the test cache. Therefore you can even set `-count=5` to both disable the test cache and to run each test five times.

Answer (score 111):

In Go11, I couldn't disable cache using `GOCACHE` with modules, I used `-count=1` instead:

```
go test -count=1
```

Prior to Go11:

```
GOCACHE=off go test
```

Or, clean test cache and run test again:

```
go clean -testcache && go test
```

Answer (score 21):

There's also `GOCACHE=off` mentioned [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22758#issuecomment-344921828).

Comment: For `go 1.11` and having go modules feature on using `GOCACHE=off` gives an error `go: cannot use modules with build cache disabled`. The better is to use suggested `-count 1`.

Comment: You're right, according to https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26809#issuecomment-410477084 `GOCACHE` will be slowly phased out in go 1.12 so using `go test -count=1 ...` is safer choice now.

Comment: `build cache is disabled by GOCACHE=off, but required as of Go 1.12`

Answer (score 15):

**For VS Code (in 2022)**

1. Open VSCode's settings.json. To open settings.json, press `Ctrl` + `,` (or `Cmd`+`,` on Mac), then click the Open JSON button shown below. Optionally, if you don't want to set this globally, you can create a `.vscode/settings.json` file at the project root.

   [image: Button for settings.json file]
2. Set the `go.testFlags` value in settings.json:

   ```
    {    
        "go.testFlags": ["-count=1"]
    }
   ```
3. Save and enjoy.

Note: these steps ensure test cache will be skipped *every time*. If you want a one-time fix, then run `go clean -testcache` in the terminal, as Marc's most-voted answer says.

Answer (score 9):

The way that I fixed this (I'm using Visual Studio Code on macOS):

Code > Preferences > Settings

Click `...` on the right hand side of the settings page

Click `Open settings.json`

Either:

1. Add the following snippet to your settings.json file

   ```
   "go.testEnvVars": {
       "GOCACHE": "off"
   }
   ```
2. Change the value of `go.testEnvVars` to include the following: `"GOCACHE": "off"`

Comment: Build cache is required as of Go 1.12 thus setting `GOCACHE` will not work with recent versions of Go. A solution for VS Code is to set `"go.testFlags": ["-count=1"]` in the settings.