# how do I run a test with "go cache" while using goland

Tags: goland

Every time I run a test with goland,it builds too slow.
It sames not using "go cache".
I have tried building with "-i" , but not usefully

Comment: What OS and Go version are you using? GoLand uses `go build` under the hood, so there shouldn't be a difference between CLI and the IDE runs. However, anti-viruses can slow down or block the IDE processes. Are you using any of it?

Comment: window and go1.16，I tried locally with terminal， it's builed without cache either

Comment: env "GOCACHE" is setted；is there other switch？

Comment: "it's builed without cache either" - how did you get it?

Comment: I build it twice，no "cached" signed,and building times are same.

Comment: According to https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go: The -i flag installs the packages that are dependencies of the target. The -i flag is deprecated. Compiled packages are cached automatically. AFAIK, "cached" is used for tests only. It is not clear how did you measure that building time the same and `go build` is not using caching. My question about anti-viruses is still actual. Window Defender can affect performance as well.

Comment: I think it's like this. E:\OpenSource\GitHub\RainbowMango\GoExpertProgrammingSourceCode\GoExpert\src>go test gotest
ok      gotest  3.434s

E:\OpenSource\GitHub\RainbowMango\GoExpertProgrammingSourceCode\GoExpert\src>go test gotest
ok      gotest  (cached)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work in the same way for non-test binaries.

Comment: My binaries are builded with command “../go.exe test -c -v -o ”,are they test binaries as you said.

Comment: Make sure that you're not using any of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882691/force-retesting-or-disable-test-caching/48882892

Comment: usually, i build test cases with goland,it's really a long time when compiles without any modification

Comment: no , i am pretty sure.

Comment: Hi chai, have you made any progress on this? I'm having the same issue.